# getting find failed errors in sikuli

Tags: java, automation, sikuli

getting this error while running sikulix with eclipse

```
18:31:08:751 >> Loading HP UFT Java Support (version 12.0.0.0) (SUN 1.7.0)
Exception in thread "main" FindFailed: Capture.PNG: (408x284) in S(0)[0,0 1366x768] E:Y, T:3.0
  Line 2759, in file Region.java

    at org.sikuli.script.Region.wait(Region.java:2759)
    at org.sikuli.script.Region.find(Region.java:2336)
    at org.sikuli.script.Region.getLocationFromTarget(Region.java:3213)
    at org.sikuli.script.Region.click(Region.java:3698)
    at org.sikuli.script.Region.click(Region.java:3683)
    at ab.main(ab.java:15)
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:"C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified Functional Testing\bin\java_shared\classes";"C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified Functional Testing\\bin\java_shared\classes\jasmine.jar"
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook
```

The code is:

```
ImagePath.setBundlePath("C:/Users/xw66/workspace/Sikul/imgs"‌​); 
Screen s = new Screen(); 
//s.wait(); 
s.doubleClick(new Pattern("C:/Users/xw66/workspace/Sikul/imgs/abc.PNG")); 
// s.click(getData("ImagePath"+"Capture.PNG"));
```

Comment: this only means that the image you were looking for, was not found on the screen. Make sure that the pattern you are using is exactly similar to the region on the screen. Also ensure that the regio is fully visible and is not hiden (or partially hidden) behing other objects.

Comment: yes i did like that only.Please assist .

Comment: sorry, have no idea what you're asking

Comment: Hi,Please let me know if you need a webex so that I can show my code.

Comment: Pattern is found on the screen not sure why i am getting the above mentioned errors.

Comment: can someone assist

Comment: Please paste your code as well

Comment: import org.sikuli.script.*;
import org.sikuli.script.Screen;
public  class ab

{


 
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ImagePath.setBundlePath("C:/Users/xw66/workspace/Sikul/imgs");
     
     Screen s = new Screen();
     
     //s.wait();
  
     s.doubleClick(new Pattern("C:/Users/xw66/workspace/Sikul/imgs/abc.PNG"));
    // s.click(getData("ImagePath"+"Capture.PNG"));
   }
}

Comment: Please embed the code into the question next. Your code looks ok by itself and the problem is likely to be elsewhere. So the first thing I'd look into is the pattern itself. So make sure that the stored pattern is absolutely similar to the region on the screen, pixel to pixel similar. Then make sure it is fully visible and not partially hidden by other objects. Next thing, and I'm just trying my luck here, what is this Java version that you're using? Is that running as a separate Java program or as a part of some other framework? I see UFT. If that's the case try simple Oracle Java.

Comment: Can we schedule a webex so that I can show you.

Answer (score 4):

Screenshots taken by Sikuli IDE works fine. But if you are taking screenshot by (cmd+shift+4) in macbook pro, resolution of the image is 144 pixel. 
1. Reduce the pixel size.
2. Right click on image > open with > Preview
3. A popup will open.
4. Click on Tools > Adjust Size > Make Resolution to 72 and click on Ok.
Now the image will work fine.

Comment: This works for mac user. Thanks for quickest way to resolve isse
Using Mac 2019 16'' Big Sur

Comment: For me it works in windows like anything, but in Linux it fails even though using with IDE and changing resolutions does not help

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes taking pictures using sikuli IDE works, but for me it was still not working.

So I found that the problem was resolution with my laptop, I was having a higher resolution which was causing problem.

So I reduced my resolution of my laptop from 1920 x 1080 ( too high for Sikuli)  to a lower resolution

**1280 x 720** and now it works like a charm.

So try reducing resolution of your system

Answer (score 1):

Just tried the Sikuli very recently and had the same Find Failed Exception issue happened.
OS -Windows 10
Solution: I tried to change the Display settings-->scale and layout--> Change the size of text, apps and other items to 125% (it was basically 150%)
Display resolution 1920*1080 still works

PS: So just be careful when you get this issue check your resolution which works best for your physical monitor. Also try to check in separate laptop with the same code, if the current one is still having issues. So if it works on other laptop all you need to do is replicate the Display settings it should work and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

@radhi I know its late to reply, but its better to follow the below instructions when using sikuli

1. Install/Setup sikuli from the sikuli jar file <https://launchpad.net/sikuli/+download>, even if you are using the maven dependency, i would still suggest you to do so
2. Run a small script from the IDE to make sure things work fine
3. Coming to capturing the images, i have seen that if i use the default screen capture present (CMD + SHT + 4) in Macbook Pro Retina display and the same from the Sikuli IDE, the IDE's image work. So its better to take images from Sikuli IDE, save the file and unzip the .sikuli file or in Mac, just right click > show package content.

Take the images and use them. This was what solved this issue for me.

If this does not help, Debug the script at the point where you are accessing the image and check if the fileUrl is pointing to the correct location

Answer (score 0):

Changing the resolution to 1280 X 720 worked for me. I can now use the snipping tool under this resolution and sikuli is able to find and click.